# How to make an Arrayformula calculation similar to Excel's table auto fill in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas, sumproduct

With Excel's Table, we can make SUMPRODUCT or INDEX formulas adjusting their reference cell automatically according to their rows.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmKvI-XDt3kGmnMKkQe8hdlLjkJp5fDC/view?usp=sharing

In the example sheet, I can fill UNIT PRICE automatically with a formula `=INDEX($I$2:$I10,MATCH(1,($H$2:$H10=B2)*($J$2:$J10<=A2)*($K$2:$K10>=A2),0))`[UNIT PRICE(1)] or a formula `=SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$10=[@[Part No]])*($J$2:$J$10<=[@[Date-In]])*($K$2:$K$10>=[@[Date-In]])*($I$2:$I$10))`[UNIT PRICE(2)]
[image: excel's table formula]

I'd like to convert this to Google Spreadsheet but couldn't find a way to generate unit price formula automatically when a new data being input to the left part without filling all range with formulas before.

I know it's hard to use INDEX or SUMPRODUCT function with ARRAYFORMULA. It's not also possible to use a combination of range skill such as `(H2:H10)&(K2:K10)` since it searches a date range not a exact date.

Your help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Sumproduct()` is itself an array formula. So, you do not need to enter it by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and this should also work in google sheet as well.

Comment: Did you tried the same formula to google sheet? You can have try on `Filter` formula like `=FILTER($I$2:$I$10,($J$2:$J$10<=A2)*($K$2:$K$10>=A2)*($H$2:$H$10=B2))`.

Comment: Hi Harun24HR. The most important object is not to enter formula for every row.

Comment: Yes, it will automatically fill other cells when you drag and down. Just enter the formula to first cell then `Double Click` small square to right down corner of the cell. It will go till last non empty cell and fill formulas automatically.

Comment: No, I meant automatically calculate without any drag and down or double clicking at all. The users of this sheet is limited to edit the price column.